# Application crashes - 'Application must have only single FDManager'

Tags: delphi, firedac

With Delphi 10.2, I'm using an application that calls a DLL for sending email. Each Application and DLL use a single FDManager for managing connection and configurations.

At times, the application crashes with the message:

> [FireDAC][Comp][Clnt]-500. Application must have only single FDManager

Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue?

**Application**

```
procedure TPhoenixWordPrintDialog.StoreEmail;    
type    
  TSendDLL = function(H : Hwnd; Recip :PChar; Subject : PChar; Body : PChar;
              Loc : PChar; UserID : PChar; Queid : Integer; AttOrderbyList : array of Integer) 
             : integer; stdcall;

var    
  Handle              : THandle;    
  SendMail            : TSendDLL;    
begin

// FDManager ConnectionDefName  is assigned with FDConnectionDefs.ini during form creation. 
//Ini file is available in the executable path for managing DB configuration  

    Handle := LoadLibrary(PChar('D:\Mapi.dll'));    
    @SendMail := GetProcAddress(Handle, 'ShowDllFormModal');    
    SendMail(Application.Handle, PChar(RecipText), PChar(SubjectText), PChar(BodyText),
                   PChar(SentLocation), PChar(SenderName), LQueID, AttachmentOrderByArray);
    
    FreeLibrary(Handle);
end;
```

**DLL**

```
    function ShowDllFormModal(H : Hwnd; Recipients : PChar; Subject : PChar;
                              Body: PChar; Loc : PChar; SenderName : PChar;
                              Queid : Integer;
                              AttOrderbyList : array of Integer):integer; stdcall;
    
    begin    
      Application.handle := H;

// One TFDConnection and TFDQuery using by PhoenixEmailForm
      PhoenixEmailForm :=TPhoenixEmailForm.Create(Application);

// FDManager, TFDConnection and TFDQuery using here. On creation of EmailDocumentDM, 
// FDManager's ConnectionDefFile is assigned with FDConnectionDefs.ini which is available in 
// DLL path        
      EMailDocumentDM := TEMailDocumentDM.Create(Application);
      PhxConnect.ConnectTDatabase(EMailDocumentDM.PhoenixMailDataLink, 
                                  PhoenixEmailForm.PhxDatLink,1);
    
      try
        //
      finally    
        if Assigned(EMailDocumentDM.PhoenixMailDataLink) then    
        begin    
          EMailDocumentDM.PhoenixMailDataLink.Close;    
          FreeandNil(EMailDocumentDM.PhoenixMailDataLink);    
        end;
    
        if Assigned(PhoenixEmailForm.PhxDatLink) then    
        begin     
          PhoenixEMailForm.PhxDatLink.Close;    
          FreeAndNil(PhoenixEmailForm.PhxDatLink);    
        end;
    
        EMailDocumentDM.MailFDManager.Close;    
      end; 
  
      Application.handle := 0;    
      PhoenixEmailForm.Free;    
      EMailDocumentDM.Free;    
    end;
```

Comment: It would appear that both your app and the DLL contain a TFDManager. The DLL does (`EMailDocumentDM.MailFDManager`). Does your app also have one?

Comment: Yes, my App also has one. But I'm closing the FDManager in the DLL (Please refer the above snippet).  If I'm not using FDManager in DLL, then the application getting freezes on freelibrary call.  I tried using FFdGUIxsilentmode=True in DLL by removing FDManager from DLL. Even then Freelibrary call gets freezes.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's closed or not. When a singleton requirement exists, that means that only one of them can be created.

Comment: If I'm not using FDManager in DLL, then the application getting freezes on freelibrary call. I tried using FFdGUIxsilentmode=True in DLL by removing FDManager from DLL. Even then Freelibrary call gets freezes.

Comment: @KenWhite: Thank you for letting me know about FDManager that can be used one in an application. I have added a new post regarding application freeze on Freelibrary call if FDManager not used in DLL. Can you please help when you get time.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70602915/delphi-firedac-application-freezes-on-freelibrary-call-after-returning-from-dll